What are the main objections aired by representatives of the countries of the world against the so-called "Pact for the future"?
I heard that countries so diverse as Russia, North Korea and Argentina expressed objections to this document. What are the main objections against this pact aired by the representatives of various countries at the UN General Assembly?

https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2024/9/24/whats-the-uns-new-pact-for-the-future-and-why-did-russia-oppose-it

and https://www.batimes.com.ar/news/world/argentina-votes-against-the-un-pact-for-the-future.phtml

@ItalianPhilosopher I've already seen this, it does not explain details.

Milei is a Libertarian.  Free market uber alles and all that.  He doesn't want to be constrained by UN "regulations", apparently esp, according to him, on trade.  Unlike other leaders he wants to be very vocal about it.  From the Al Jazeera article, it seems many other countries think it's a lot of usual UN fluffing about, with little in terms of concrete steps.  Milei being Milei, he wanted to pick a fight about it.

@ItalianPhilosopher does the pact promote any trade regulations though?

Milei's ambassador seems to claim it would be trade restrictive.  “Hunger will end by guaranteeing more trade, not less; and development can be achieved by strengthening respect for institutions, fundamentally prioritizing respect for private property,” Mondino said.  https://buenosairesherald.com/world/international-relations/argentina-refuses-to-sign-un-pact-for-the-future-at-new-york-summit

TLDR: the document itself is usual fluff that the UNGA puts out dozens of times a year.
Why Russia (and its allies like North Korea, Iran, Belarus, Nicaragua, Syria) [in part] chose to vote against it is that their amendment[s] were not included. These were mostly complaints about sanctions, but phrased as sovereignist concerns like:

its system shall not intervene in matters which are essentially within the domestic jurisdiction of any State.

Slightly more interestingly, from Roger's answer, Russia complained about the calls for nuclear disarmament in document. Relatedly, Russia's leadership makes a public nuclear threat [against the West] about every other day now. Also note that conversely, nuclear disarmament organizations conversely complained that the pact/document was too weak in this respect, so it was probably nothing unusual in this respect, in the UNGA tradition of blah.
As for Milei, he complained that the document/pact has a "socialist" agenda, doesn't promote freedom, and doesn't achieve world peace. But Argentina did not actually vote for the Russian amendment. Nor did it actually vote against the document as a whole, or even abstain on record (like e.g. China did). Argentina merely didn't vote.

If you're confused about the "no action on draft amendment" bit, that was the last vote on the matter. The document was then adopted by the UNGA without a vote (record).

It seems to me after research, the main objection of Millei was the climate change agenda.

@Anixx: possibly. They seem not to have pulled out of the Paris accord though.

Official statements from the various participants are available, including one from Russia.  They mention a number of specific objections.
I've quoted the relevant passages and including Google Translations into English, which are probably not ideal but the best I can do -- if anyone can suggest more-accurate translations, please do so in the comments and I'll make the necessary edits.

Руководствуясь именно таким настроем, российская сторона с самого
начала принимала активное участие в процессе выработки «Пакта будущего».
Мы не только руководствовались национальными интересами, но
ориентировались на приоритеты Мирового большинства. Наша делегация
неизменно была конструктивна и открыта к диалогу в интересах компромисса.

Guided by precisely this spirit, the Russian side, from the very 
began to take an active part in the process of developing the “Pact of the Future”. 
We were not only guided by national interests, but 
were guided by the priorities of the World Majority. Our delegation 
was invariably constructive and open to dialogue in the interests of compromise.


Несмотря на это, в итоговых версиях Пакта и приложений к нему
сохранились неконсенсусные и неприемлемые элементы, которые не
способствуют достижению заявленных целей Саммита и чреваты негативными
последствиями для самих основ работы ООН.

Despite this, in the final versions of the Pact and its annexes 
non-consensus and unacceptable elements remain that are not 
contribute to achieving the stated goals of the Summit and are fraught with negative 
consequences for the very foundations of the UN's work.


Исходя из этого Россия не стала блокировать принятие Пакта и
присоединилась к озвученному ранее заявлению Группы друзей в защиту
Устава ООН. При этом мы недвусмысленно дистанцировались от консенсуса по
Пакту и Цифровому договору, особенно по озвученным ниже элементам.

Based on this, Russia did not block the adoption of the Pact and 
joined the previously announced statement of the Group of Friends in defense of 
UN Charter. At the same time, we have clearly distanced ourselves from the consensus on 
The Pact and the Digital Treaty, especially on the elements outlined below.


В конкретном плане не можем поддержать формулировки, нацеленные на
подрыв межправительственной природы Организации. Неприемлемо и
избирательное цитирование общепризнанных принципов международного
права. Так, в документе прямо не упомянут принцип невмешательства во
внутренние дела суверенных государств, равно как и принцип сотрудничества.

In concrete terms, we cannot support language aimed at 
undermining the intergovernmental nature of the Organization. Unacceptable and 
selective quotation of generally accepted principles of international 
rights. Thus, the document does not directly mention the principle of non-interference in 
the internal affairs of sovereign states, as well as the principle of cooperation.


Мы, как и целый ряд государств, ведущих суверенную внешнюю
политику, не можем поддержать укрепление роли Верховного комиссара ООН
по правам человека, который, прославился предвзятостью и потаканием
западным интересам.

We, like a number of states leading sovereign foreign 
politics, we cannot support strengthening the role of the UN High Commissioner 
on human rights, which has become notorious for bias and pandering 
Western interests.


Выступаем против форсирования процесса ядерного разоружения. На
фоне игнорирования принципа равной и неделимой безопасности подобные
идеи носят откровенно нереалистичный, если не сказать деструктивный,
характер.

We oppose speeding up the process of nuclear disarmament. On 
against the backdrop of ignoring the principle of equal and indivisible security, such 
ideas are frankly unrealistic, not to say destructive, 
character.


Содержит серьезные изъяны и «Глобальный цифровой договор». В нем
идет речь о попытке уравнивания неправительственных субъектов с
государствами при принятии решений по международной технологической
повестке, а также создание на этом треке дополнительных обзорных
механизмов с неясными мандатами.

The Global Digital Compact also contains serious flaws. In it 
we are talking about an attempt to equate non-governmental actors with 
states when making decisions on international technological 
agenda, as well as the creation of additional overviews on this track 
mechanisms with unclear mandates.


Безусловно, принятые на Саммите документы содержат некоторые идеи,
отвечающие ожиданиям Мирового большинства. К таковым относятся реформа
глобальной финансовой архитектуры, расширение доступа к технологиям и
преодоление «цифрового разрыва» в интересах достижения Целей устойчивого
развития. Хотели бы поприветствовать «Декларацию будущих поколений»,
которая наглядно демонстрирует, что консенсус в Организации возможен, если
к этому есть политическая воля.

Of course, the documents adopted at the Summit contain some ideas 
meeting the expectations of the World Majority. These include reform
global financial architecture, expanding access to technology and 
bridging the digital divide to achieve the Sustainable Development Goals 
development. We would like to welcome the “Declaration of Future Generations”, 
which clearly demonstrates that consensus in the Organization is possible if 
There is political will for this.


Google translations are not even grammatical, better use any AI to translate, such as ChatGPT or Claude.

You know, maybe a more directly illuminating reason can be cited from Al Jazeera : As Israel’s war on Gaza, the Russia-Ukraine war and the civil war in Sudan continue to claim lives, it (note:  the Pact) recommits the UN to support the International Court of Justice (ICJ).

@ItalianPhilosopher That's a good answer to a good question, but it's not the question posed here, in my opinion.

@Anixx - Google Translate is an "AI." It uses a large transformer model very much like GPT. And the translation does not look terribly ungrammatical. What should be changed is the formatting: the code formatting interferes with mobile readability and screen reader accessibility.

@Obie2.0 no, Google translate is not a large language model like ChatGPT. If you use it to translate into other languages, the result is much worse, usually gibberish.

@Anixx - Google Translate has been using a transformer encoder since 2020 (GPT is "generative pretrained transformer," BTW). It was pure LSTM before that. Assuming that the transformer encoder is "large" in terms of the number of parameters - a subjective judgement, but very likely true - yes, it would be properly described as a large language model (BERT, for instance, would be an example of an encoder transformer model). Of course, even the earlier LSTM architecture was also an "AI," as much as transformers are, anyway.

Furthermore, since earlier this year, Google Translate has been using PaLM, which is a purely transformer-based LLM, in case someone wants to claim that the RNN decoder in earlier iterations somehow disqualified it. Any limitations that you are seeing are limitations in a specific transformer-based LLM, be it the older transformer-encoder RNN-decoder version still hanging around, or the more recent pure transformer models.

@Obie2.0 all current LLMs, even quite weak ones produce mostly grammatical text and understand the context. Google Translate does not.

It doesn't seem as if you understand the concepts in the field. An LLM does not not cease to be such merely because you dislike it, or even because its peformance is bad. To give an example that should be obvious, a transformer that is initialized but not trained still has just as many parameters, making it just as "large," and its architecture is exactly the same, but its performance will be quite poor on tasks of interest. Perhaps this misconception could be a consequence of high primativity on your part?
